# Opening a pre-existing entity without an ID

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-4

If a field called *new_something* on a form of entity *Stuff*  is changed, I'm running a check to see if there's an instance of an entity of type *Thing* with corresponding value on its *new_something_else* field. This works perfectly.

Now, the customer'd like to to smack up the found, corresponding instance on the screen as well. Is there a smooth way to do that using the value of *new_something* or do I have to fetch the ID of the pre-existing entity and use it with redirection of the browser?

It seems to me like an ugly and unsupported approach but perhaps that's how it's supposed to be done in 4.0 - other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to retrieve the ID of the other record and use that to open the other entity.

However [URL addressable forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150850.aspx) is a supported option.

Comment: I'm looking at the list in the lower part of the article you've linked to but there's no section for *Lead*. That's not a custom entity but still not listed there. What'd be the URL to retrieve an instance of a *Lead* given that we have its GUID?

Comment: I believe in that situation you can treat it as a custom entity.

Comment: Apparently, one just need to type in *leads* for *Lead* entity (five characters limitation, I guess), while *Account* is abbreviated to *accts*. Weird...